# Trying to identify this famous person. Young Johnny Unitas?

Tags: sports, 1960s, famous-people

[image][image]I was told by a friend that it looked like a young Johnny Unitas

Comment: Do you have any other information about the photo (where it was taken, when, etc.)?  I seriously doubt it is Unitas - he buzzed the hair on the sides of his head through most of his football career, and later parted it on the right, not the left.

Comment: Thx,, I can see that now. It came from a collection of photographs from a photographer in San Diego, CA., He has a lot Vietnam, '64 Stones, USO, etc. these were among them. There are 2 other images showing him giving a speach at a podium, and another that has him in the back of a car with (wife) waving as if a Grand Marshall in a parade.

Comment: Can you post the other images? More context is always better.

Comment: That isn't Johnny Unitas.  Saw enough of his face on TV as a boy (while he was still playing, we lived about an hour and a half from Baltimore) and [that face isn't his](http://www.johnnyunitas.com/about-unitas/bio).

Comment: If you are still interested, you should post the other photos.

Answer (score 2):

I can't be 100% sure, but it doesn't look like Unitas (who buzzed the hair on the sides of his head through much of his football career.

My best guess given that these appear to have come from the San Diego area would be [Glenard P. Lipscomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glenard_P._Lipscomb), who served as Congressman for the California 56th district from 1953 to 1970. His U.S. Congress file photo from 1969 bears quite a resemblance:

[image: Glenard P. Lipscomb]

<sup>Image courtesy of Wikipedia</sup>

Comment: http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0257/3165/products/RSD92891_grande.jpeg?v=1455556988

Comment: @Topia - I'm not sure that's Virginia Lipscomb in your original pictures, but they did have a daughter.  Unfortunately I can't even find her name anywhere.